# Xcode 7.3: import Module displayed with strikethrough

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7.3

After upgrading Xcode to 7.3, I just found that some modules are stricken out while importing, like in this screenshot:

[image]

But after adding the module (so just pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>) everything is fine. What does that mean? The module here is written in Swift and works fine.

Comment: Yeah! same I got when i was importing **CoraData** module

Comment: Yes, and MapKit too.

Comment: `CoreData` is not struck through for me, but others like `ClockKit` and `CoreLocation` are.

Comment: Its strange - because everything work fine (and it happens not to all modules) Maybe a Bug, or maybe a Feature which does not make any sense ;)

Comment: @PetahChristian see I have added snapshot I am getting for CoreData too [**here**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ3l1.png), but interesting MapKit looks fine with me

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a bug. We have fixed it in [218010af](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/218010afb94bcb120b9648440c35708c536cb301), which should be included in the Swift 2.2.1 release and is included in the [2016-04-12-a developer snapshot](https://github.com/apple/swift/releases/tag/swift-DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-2016-04-12-a).

Comment: "This is a bug that was fixed in version X" is an answer -- but this answer doesn't mention the version, so it's not very helpful to future readers.

Comment: It is still an answer, if its now clear that its just a bug, already reported and hopefully fixed in the next release.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Updated. The commit ID would already be implicitly associated with a release, but I've named it explicitly for clarity.

Comment: Xcode 7.3.1 (currently available for download as a [GM seed](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/)) includes Swift 2.2.1, according to [the Swift download page](https://swift.org/download/), although `xcrun swift -v` still calls it version 2.2.

Answer (score 24):

The strikethrough occurs if you try to import a module that has already been imported by your file or module:

[image: import]

In this case, I have already imported Foundation (which implicitly imports CoreFoundation), so Xcode is telling you that there is no need to import either module again.

Comment: While Xcode behaves correctly in your case, where you have intentionally duplicated the module `import`, misbehaviour explained in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35671637/1492173) is still the case. The module required to be imported but displayed in strikethrough font.

Comment: @EugeneDubinin right, that's why I said it was potentially a possible duplicate, not for-sure-a100% duplicate.

Comment: If the class Dog is a subclass to class Animal, and animal has imported e.g. Alamofire, then you import Alamofire in Dog Alamofire gets a red strikethrough as well. But it is misleading, since subclasses cant use the imports of its superclass, so I guess this is a bug as well...

Comment: This also happens if Foundation is imported indirectly via an include from the bridging header file.

Answer (score 6):

It usually happens when a framework is already imported by any other framework you have already been imported.

For example, **UIKit** is already imported with **Foundation** so you don't need to import it manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed the order of the imports

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import LayerKit
import Atlas  < red line


import Foundation
import UIKit
import Atlas
import LayerKit
```

Some notes that may be causing it:

- LayerKit importing Atlas even though LayerKit is the lower level API
  Atlas is the UI layer
- Both were Cocoapod imports
- Error appeared when I created an 2nd Schema for App Store/Enteprise
  releases and cleaned one and switch to the other.
- Deleting Derived
  Data didnt clear it.
- So tried rearranging them and red line disappeared