# Get the first character from values of array in Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, indexing, character

I have created an Array with two Strings:

```
var palabras: [String] = ["Gato", "Martillo"]
```

And I want to show the first character of this two String of the Array.

I have tried with:

```
letraLabel.text = palabras[round - 1].startIndex.advancedBy(0)
```

But i get an error: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
I don't know what it is mean.

And i have tried too:

```
letraLabel.text = palabras[round - 1].startIndex
```

I get an error: 
Cannot assign value of type 'Index' (aka 'String.CharacterView.Index') to type 'String?'

And finally I have tried:

```
letraLabel.text = palabras[round - 1][palabras.startIndex]
```

But also I got an error:
'subscript' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, see the documentation comment for discussion

How can I get the first character of the two word of the Array?
So, is necessary import Foundation for obtain the first character of a String?
By the way, when i write "import Foundation" the compiller show me Foundation with a crossed-out line.

Comment: About your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180575/xcode-7-3-import-module-displayed-with-strikethrough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
letraLabel.text = String(palabras[round - 1].first!)
```

If you want to create another array with just the first letters:

```
let palabras = ["Gato", "Martillo"]
let firstLetters = palabras.map { String($0.first!) }
print(firstLetters) // ["G", "M"]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for palabra in palabras {
    let letra = palabra[palabra.startIndex]
    // do something with letra here...
}
```

Or, if you don't want to iterate through every `palabra`, something like this might work:

```
let palabra = palabras[0]
let letra = palabra[palabra.startIndex]
// do something with letra here...
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close I think. Give this a try

```
let charStr = palabras[round - 1]
letraLabel.text = charStr.substringToIndex(charStr.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
```

or if you want all the first characters concatenated together:

```
letraLabel.text = palabras.map({ $0.substringToIndex($0.startIndex.advancedBy(1)) }).joinWithSeparator("")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform this easier it's nested but get's the job done. Say you had a variable with two string. You could simply use

```
someLabel.text = firstName.characters.first?.description + lastName.characters.first?.description
```