# Why import UIKit/Foundation has strikethrough in an old project?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm currently working on an old project and each time when I tried to import UIKit or Foundation there is always a strikethrough, this is the only framework I wanted to import.
I tested to generate a UIView without `import UIKit` line and it works...

Is there a build setting can do that? Does anyone know why ?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you importing anything else in that file?

Comment: @Sweeper no that's the only framework I imported, it happens in any Swift files of the project

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36182707/1187415: “The strikethrough occurs if you try to import a module that has already been imported by your file or module.”

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the link, but there is only UIKit imported. Besides, I don't really understand "has already been imported by your file or module.”, how to import UIKit by a module? This happens in the main project

Answer (score 0):

It might be linked to the **Build Settings** titled `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` which, if set to `YES`, will always embed all the standard libraries (like `Foundation`, `UIKit`, `WebKit`, etc.).

You could disable the setting and test it again.

Comment: I've tried to disable it but the problem is still... do you know what is the advantage of enabling this ?