# Xcode import framework's name scratched?

Tags: xcode, module, ios-frameworks

What does it mean when you try to import a framework in a class file and you see it's name in the autosuggestions scratched? Like for example:

[image]

Now, I thought that maybe it means that I don't need to import it in order to use it, but that's not the case. I've seen this many times for different frameworks and I have no idea what it means... can someone enlighten me please?

Comment: What makes you think that you need the import. Does the project not compile otherwise?

Comment: @Abizern - if I don't import it, it doesn't compile

Comment: File it as a bug: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180575/xcode-7-3-import-module-displayed-with-strikethrough and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671637/the-module-required-to-be-imported-but-displayed-in-strikethrough-font-in-xcode

Comment: @Abizern oh, it's a bug. Okay. I thought I was doing something wrong. Thanks